# FIPS to ISO 3166 codes for divisions/regions

Tags: geolocation, geocoding

I have a database with FIPS codes for regions and I would like to convert them to ISO for example, 
PL74 for poland should translate to LD and CA01 should translate to alberta for canada
Looking just for a list not a service if possible

BING location api always returns the ISO for a region and not FIPS

Answer (score 1):

I found this website. Don't know the accuracy though. If you click a country you will get the fips and Iso codes for regions.
http://www.statoids.com/wab.html